# Can't resolve all parameters for ... ([object Object],[object Object], ?, ?)

Tags: angular

I've been put on someone else's code and there is a class that is used as a base for other component. When I'm trying to ng serve --aot (or build --prod) I get the following.

```js
    @Component({
      ...,
      providers: [NgProgress]
    })
    export class ReferentielComponent {
        vars...

      constructor(referentielService: ReferentielService, ngProgressService: NgProgress, referentielName: string, referentielViewName: string) {
        this.ngProgressService = ngProgressService;
        this.referentielName = referentielName;
        this.referentielViewName = referentielViewName;
        this.referentielService = referentielService;
      }
    }
```

One of the extends

```js
    @Component({
      ...,
      providers: [ReferentielService, NgProgress ]
    })
    export class ProgrammeComponent extends ReferentielComponent {
      constructor(referentielService: ReferentielService, ngProgressService: NgProgress ) {
        super(referentielService, ngProgressService, "programme", "programme");
      }
    }
```

ReferentielService

```js
@Injectable()
export class ReferentielService {

  private referentielUrl = environment.restApiUrl + '/referentiel';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getReferentiels(tableName: string) {
    return this._http.get<Referentiel[]>(this.referentielUrl + '/' + tableName);
  }
}
```

And I get

```
Failed to compile.

Can't resolve all parameters for ReferentielComponent in /src/app/components/referentiel/referentiel.component.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, ?).
```

I've tried to put default values and wasn't able to comprehend or use the other cases I've seen on SO.

I'm working on Angular 4.

Comment: Does `ReferentielService` have `@Injectable()`?

Comment: @jburtondev It does `@Injectable()
export class ReferentielService` it's all my http.get/post

Comment: I see, remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Same error that it can't resolve all parameters. I should have precised that this is with --aot flag

Comment: It is because you are injecting two strings to the constructor of ReferentielComponent and the DI does not know what values to give to them to instantiate the component. You need to provide a value for those two string in the DI and use @Inject()

Comment: I tried with `@Inject("") referentielName: string, @Inject("") referentielViewName: string` and it compiled \o/. Now I have 278 errors to correct ... but I guess that the "Can't resolve all parameters" is now resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't understand what is the string, because there is no way for him to tell at compilation time. So you have to manually tell him by using [@Inject()](https://v4.angular.io/api/core/Inject)

In this case my constructor would look like this :

```js
constructor(referentielService: ReferentielService, ngProgressService: NgProgress, @Inject("") referentielName: string, @Inject("") referentielViewName: string) {
```

I personally don't need to inject anything else than an empty string, at least for now.